# what is ".__class__.name__" attribute of an python object?

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

I was going through `pytorch codebase` for face generation using DCGAN and come across this code.

```
def weights_init(m):
    classname = m.__class__.__name__
    if classname.find('Conv') != -1:
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0.0, 0.02)
    elif classname.find('BatchNorm') != -1:
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 1.0, 0.02)
        nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0)
```

I don't understand line 2 `classname = m.__class__.__name__` and line 3 `if classname.find('Conv') != -1:` from above method `weights_init`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your title question, Python's language reference [standard types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) documentation explains it best.

My class `Hero` is basically user defined callable type and it has `special attribute` `__name__`. These attributes are `writable` and I can modify it as well.

[image]

Python String's `.find()` method quote from [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

> Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found
>   within the slice s[start:end]. Optional arguments start and end are
>   interpreted as in slice notation. Return -1 if sub is not found.

Basically, your sample code is trying to find `Conv` in the class name and proceed further accordingly.